# One of the best gift / gifts in my life is love

Tags: determiners, singular-vs-plural

> One of the best gift / gifts in my life is love.

When I indicate a single thing (love) as best, after "One of the best" would it be gift or gifts?

Comment: It's your initial ***one of*** that forces you to use plural ***gifts***. Without it, you'd use singular: *"The best **gift** in my life is love"*.

Answer (score 7):

It would be *gifts*, since you are choosing one thing from a group - you cannot choose one from a group of one. Think of it as

> One of the *plural* is love.

as in:

> One of the *various emotions that humans experience* is love.
>   One of the *four-letter words* is love.
>   One of the *meanings of a heart symbol* is love.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be 'gifts'. Further examples could be the following:

- pistachio is one of the few flavors that appeals to me
- This is one of the cars that run on hydrogen
- He is one of the people who make money

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously 'gifts' i.e. the plural form. Both the answers are correct but here I'll try to make it simpler for you.

The 'X' in *one of X' is plural. That's because you are choosing that *one* from *several* (the case is different while dealing with mass nouns though). Let's take the word *gift* in concern. But before that two things are to be clarified:

1) *One of...* refers to the *gift* and not *love.*

2) If you are referring to **the best gift** in your life, it'll be *the best gift in your life* not *one of the...* because the moment you *insert* **one of the...** it induces choosing *one from several*.

Check out this to make it clear.

Tell me -- is it *one of the **balls** is yellow* **OR** *one of the **ball** is yellow?*

Think this way -- There are many balls, one of  ***<del>it</del> them*** is yellow. You used *them* so ..it's plural!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think one of the biggest is a good grammar. Think of it this way- how many biggest can we have, only one. So, why would you say one of the biggest trees or men. You may say the biggest man or the biggest tree.

Comment: A superlative may also be used to designate multiple entities: all of those trees, for instance, which are markedly "bigger" than all the rest.

Comment: Interesting take. However, try typing `"one of the biggest"` into Google and watch what happens. It's a well-established phrase.